# Migration from Loopback 3 to Loopback 4

Tags: loopbackjs

is there any automated way to migrate project in Loopback 3 to Loopback 4?
For example, I have model definition in JSON:

```
{"name": "Item",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "forceId": true,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "Date",
      "postgresql": {
        "dbDefault": "now()"
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to auto-create the same model in LB4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update 13 May 2020

The LoopBack 4 documentation now has a comprehensive [migration guide](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/migration-overview.html). CLI tooling are also available to help migrate certain compon

### Original answer

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

There is no clear migration path from LoopBack 3 to LoopBack 4 *yet*. We are discussing different approaches to migration in the GitHub issue [loopback-next#1849](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1849), you may find some of the information useful. We encourage all LB3 users to join the discussion.

Note that LB4 does not support all LB3 features yet, the list of missing features is maintained in the GitHub issue [loopback-next#1920](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1920).

Comment: Hope lb4 reaches more heights and success!

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to do such migrations. LB4 is very different in terms of model creation than LB3, in lB3 model configurations were stored in the form of JSON format, whereas, in LB4 is defined in typescript by the means of @model and @property decorators.
May be in future there will be some way.